# sitemap xml parsing in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-sitemap

My xml structure are bellow

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>hello world 1</loc>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>this is image loc 1</image:loc>
            <image:title>this is image title 1</image:title>
        </image:image>
        <lastmod>2019-06-19</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.25</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>hello world 2</loc>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>this is image loc 2</image:loc>
            <image:title>this is image title 2</image:title>
        </image:image>
        <lastmod>2020-03-19</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.25</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

i want to get only

```
hello world 1
hello world 2
```

My python code is bellow:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for url in root.findall('url'):
    loc = url.find('loc').text
    print(loc)
```

unfortunately it gives me nothing.

But when I change my xml to

```
<urlset>
    <url>
        <loc>hello world 1</loc>
        <lastmod>2019-06-19</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.25</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>hello world 2</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-03-19</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.25</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

it gives me correct result.

```
hello world 1
hello world 2
```

What can i do to get correct result without changing my xml? Because it doesn't make any sense to modify a 10000+ lines of file.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (inelegant) fix to your code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# In find/findall, prefix namespaced tags with the full namespace in braces
for url in root.findall('{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}url'):
    loc = url.find('{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc').text
    print(loc)
```

This is because you have to qualify you tag names with the namespace under which your XML is defined. The details on how use the `find` and `findall` methods with namespaces are from [Parse XML namespace with Element Tree findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039947/parse-xml-namespace-with-element-tree-findall)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with namespace, this is simpler solution then the accepted answer, and bit more elegant, using generic xpath query:

```
import lxml.etree


tree = lxml.etree.parse('test.xml')

for url in tree.xpath("//*[local-name()='loc']/text()"):
    print(url)
```

If you prefer to utilise xml namespace, you should do it this way:

```
import lxml.etree


tree = lxml.etree.parse('test.xml')

namespaces = {
    'sitemapindex': 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9',
}

for url in tree.xpath("//sitemapindex:loc/text()", namespaces=namespaces):
    print(url)
```

If you prefer to load xml data directly from memory, instead from file, you can use lxml.etree.fromstring instead of lxml.etree.parse.